# Log4j2.xml monitorInterval not working

Tags: classpath, log4j2

Hi I am using log4j2 and I have written a log4j2.xml file which is under

```
src/main/resources
```

I have also added an attribute

```
<Configuration monitorInterval="60">
```

But this doesn't work. How do I add this file to my classpath using Intellij.

I have included the following in my pom.xml under build tag:

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: Basically I want to update logging level in log4j2.xml during runtime. However unable to get it working. Is there some code which has to be written in java files?

Comment: How do you determine that it doesn't work? Can you show us more information?

Comment: I am changing the log level when my application is running from info to error. Even then the info level logs are getting printed to STDOUT. If however I restart my server the changes are reflected.

Answer (score 2):

You should update the log level in `target/classes/log4j2.xml` instead of `src/main/resources/log4j2.xml`

---

**UPDATE:**

Here's my test and it works for me

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {
  static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    while (true) {
      logger.info("info");
      logger.error("error");
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
  }
}
```

**log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="5">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I changed the level in `target/classes/log4j2.xml` from info to error and the app only output the error log messages.

Comment: I guess we are not supposed to change the target directory, though not sure as I am new to maven.
P.S: It din't work either.

Comment: You can have a try.

Comment: The `target/classes/log4j2.xml` configuration file is the one that you're using during runtime.

Comment: monitorInterval check for configuration changes every 5 seconds?

Comment: It's just an example, you can set it to any value, e.g. "60".

Comment: Yes, I know that. I was asking does it work in the way I describe. Maybe I am missing out there.

Comment: Yes, it checks for changes every 5 seconds.

Comment: It is working for the case described by you. However it is not working when I am running my application on Tomcat server. I will explore more on this.